# Find a character from format string function

Tags: c, format-string

I am trying to understand format string vulnerability and I am working on print out the `secret[1]` value with modify the vulnerable code, but my trial doesn't work and I only see `secret[0]`. I am not able to print `secret[1]`.

here is the console output:

```
$ ./vul_prog
The variable secret's address is 0xbffff2f8 (on stack)
The variable secret's value is 0x 804fa88 (on heap)
secret[0]'s address is 0x 804fa88 (on heap)
secret[1]'s address is 0x 804fa8c (on heap)
Please enter a decimal integer
1
Please enter a string
%x.%x.%x.%x.%x.%x.%x.%x.%x.%x.%x.%x
bffff2fc.b7fd6b48.0.b7fff000.1.804fa88.252e7825.78252e78.2e78252e.252e7825.78252e78.2e78252e
The original secrets: 0x44 -- 0x55
The new secrets: 0x44 -- 0x55

$ ./vul_prog
The variable secret's address is 0xbffff2f8 (on stack)
The variable secret's value is 0x 804fa88 (on heap)
secret[0]'s address is 0x 804fa88 (on heap)
secret[1]'s address is 0x 804fa8c (on heap)
Please enter a decimal integer
1234567
Please enter a string
%x.%x.%x.%x.%x.%x.%s
Segmentation fault
```

code:

```
/* vul_prog.c */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SECRET1 0x44
#define SECRET2 0x55
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char user_input[100];
    int *secret;
    int int_input;
    int a, b, c, d; /* other variables, not used here.*/
    /* The secret value is stored on the heap */
    secret = (int *) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    /* getting the secret */
    secret[0] = SECRET1; secret[1] = SECRET2;

    printf("The variable secret's address is 0x%8x (on stack)\n",
           (unsigned int)&secret);

    printf("The variable secret's value is 0x%8x (on heap)\n",
           (unsigned int)secret);

    printf("secret[0]'s address is 0x%8x (on heap)\n",
           (unsigned int)&secret[0]);

    printf("secret[1]'s address is 0x%8x (on heap)\n",
           (unsigned int)&secret[1]);

    printf("Please enter a decimal integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &int_input); /* getting an input from user */
    printf("Please enter a string\n");
    scanf("%s", user_input); /* getting a string from user */

    /* Vulnerable place */
    printf(user_input);
    printf("\n");

    /* Verify whether your attack is successful */
    printf("The original secrets: 0x%x -- 0x%x\n", SECRET1, SECRET2);
    printf("The new secrets: 0x%x -- 0x%x\n", secret[0], secret[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Is that any problem?

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointer values, not `%8x`.

Comment: `%s` will cause `printf(user_input)` to access memory until it finds a '\0'.  It looks like it segfaults before it finds a nul.

Comment: Thank you for your reminding, but I am working exactly on printf(user_input) to access memory.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `printf` with a user entered format string is very risky and any format specifier that does not correspond to an actual argument causes undefined behavior.

But in your case, this **is** the goal of the question.

From the first output, you can see that although no arguments were passed to `printf`, the sixth argument it finds for `%x` is the pointer `secret` in the caller frame.

If you pass the string `"%x%x%x%x%x%.2s"`, you should be able to get the contents of the secret array because the value used by `printf` for the `%s` will be the pointer `secret`.

If you pass the string `"%x%x%x%x%x%hhn"`, the value of the pointer `secret` will be used as the location to store the number of characters output so far, thereby modifying the actual `secret`.

You can use a different format to change this number of characters. For example `%.0s` should just ignore the argument producing no output and `%65c` should produce 65 bytes of output. Hence if you want to store `'A'` in the secret, this format string might work: `"%.0s%.0s%.0s%.0s%65d%hhn"`.

Of course this is **completely** system and compiler specific, indeed this approach would not work on 64-bit systems, but you are testing on a 32-bit system.

Comment: Thank you for your answering, but I am still questioning on why I can only access secret[0] value, but not secret[1]. I know 804fa88 is the location of secret[0], but why secret[1] not in the next location on the output _bffff2fc.b7fd6b48.0.b7fff000.12d687. **804fa88** .252e7825_

Comment: You could access both `secret[0]` and `secret[1]` with the format `%hn`. For example `"%.0s%.0s%.0s%.0s%16706d%hn"` should produce 16KB of output and set the secret to `BA`.